# How to do a rolling sum, each row need to include the sum of previous rows in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table [visit]. I need to get the rows grouped by user_id with sum of visit_duration_seconds for when order_number is null, for example, for user [2875636] i'll get: 61+151+33+13. Each row should include the sum of the rows before it.
Plz also refer RESULT column in expected result below

> ```
> user_id   starttime           visit_duration_seconds  order_number
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:03:50 61  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:08:18 151 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:15:43 33  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:16:37 13  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:18:01 2011                     10177888
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:24:35 1172                     10177884
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:32:03 4731    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:33:27 407 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:37:29 74  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:48:55 80  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:05:00 1955    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:14:12 326 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:23:39 972 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:33:05 5440    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:35:48 43  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:41:10 66  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:42:03 100 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:42:12 2414                     10177940
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:49:05 432                  10177925
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:50:19 183 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:52:46 2061    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:52:53 400 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:00:47 338 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:08:58 216 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:14:21 58  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:14:26 196 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:19:14 2189    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:21:29 424 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:24:42 999 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:01:39 1810    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:02:54 525 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:10:06 27  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:12:08 282 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:51:02 6   
> 2875636   2013-01-16 22:18:34 173 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 23:02:58 318 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 23:45:37 207 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:01:45 18  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:16:45 39  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:22:55 656 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:25:54 1852    
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:29:23 688 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:47:26 2258                       10177846
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:57:41 572 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:06:47 1431    
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:18:32 29  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:21:57 45  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:29:23 16  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:36:47 490
> ```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
user_id starttime           visit_duration_seconds  order_number        RESULT
2875636 2013-01-16 18:03:50 61                                      61
2875636 2013-01-16 18:08:18 151                                     212
2875636 2013-01-16 18:15:43 33                                      245
2875636 2013-01-16 18:16:37 13                                      258
2875636 2013-01-16 18:18:01 2011                     10177888           0
2875636 2013-01-16 18:24:35 1172                     10177884           0
2875636 2013-01-16 18:32:03 4731                                        4731
2875636 2013-01-16 18:33:27 407                                     5138
2875636 2013-01-16 18:37:29 74                                      5212
2875636 2013-01-16 18:48:55 80                                      ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:05:00 1955                                        ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:14:12 326                                     ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:23:39 972 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:33:05 5440    
2875636 2013-01-16 19:35:48 43  
2875636 2013-01-16 19:41:10 66  
2875636 2013-01-16 19:42:03 100 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:42:12 2414                     10177940
2875636 2013-01-16 19:49:05 432                  10177925
2875636 2013-01-16 19:50:19 183 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:52:46 2061    
2875636 2013-01-16 19:52:53 400 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:00:47 338 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:08:58 216 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:14:21 58  
2875636 2013-01-16 20:14:26 196 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:19:14 2189    
2875636 2013-01-16 20:21:29 424 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:24:42 999 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:01:39 1810    
2875636 2013-01-16 21:02:54 525 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:10:06 27  
2875636 2013-01-16 21:12:08 282 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:51:02 6   
2875636 2013-01-16 22:18:34 173 
2875636 2013-01-16 23:02:58 318 
2875636 2013-01-16 23:45:37 207 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:01:45 18  
3018868 2013-01-16 16:16:45 39  
3018868 2013-01-16 16:22:55 656 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:25:54 1852    
3018868 2013-01-16 16:29:23 688 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:47:26 2258                       10177846
3018868 2013-01-16 16:57:41 572 
3018868 2013-01-16 17:06:47 1431    
3018868 2013-01-16 17:18:32 29  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:21:57 45  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:29:23 16  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:36:47 490
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a table using your sample data:

```
SQL> create table mytable (user_id,starttime,visit_duration_seconds,order_number)
  2  as
  3  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:03:50','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 61, null from dual union all
  4  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:08:18','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 151, null from dual union all
  5  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:15:43','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 33, null from dual union all
  6  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:16:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 13, null from dual union all
  7  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:18:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2011,10177888 from dual union all
  8  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:24:35','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1172,10177884 from dual union all
  9  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:32:03','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 4731, null from dual union all
 10  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:33:27','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 407, null from dual union all
 11  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:37:29','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 74, null from dual union all
 12  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 18:48:55','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 80, null from dual union all
 13  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:05:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1955, null from dual union all
 14  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:14:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 326, null from dual union all
 15  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:23:39','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 972, null from dual union all
 16  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:33:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 5440, null from dual union all
 17  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:35:48','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 43, null from dual union all
 18  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:41:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 66, null from dual union all
 19  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:42:03','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 100, null from dual union all
 20  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:42:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2414,10177940 from dual union all
 21  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:49:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 432,10177925 from dual union all
 22  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:50:19','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 183, null from dual union all
 23  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:52:46','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2061, null from dual union all
 24  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 19:52:53','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 400, null from dual union all
 25  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:00:47','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 338, null from dual union all
 26  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:08:58','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 216, null from dual union all
 27  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:14:21','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 58, null from dual union all
 28  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:14:26','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 196, null from dual union all
 29  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:19:14','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2189, null from dual union all
 30  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:21:29','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 424, null from dual union all
 31  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 20:24:42','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 999, null from dual union all
 32  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 21:01:39','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1810, null from dual union all
 33  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 21:02:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 525, null from dual union all
 34  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 21:10:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 27, null from dual union all
 35  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 21:12:08','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 282, null from dual union all
 36  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 21:51:02','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 6, null from dual union all
 37  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 22:18:34','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 173, null from dual union all
 38  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 23:02:58','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 318, null from dual union all
 39  select 2875636, to_date('2013-01-16 23:45:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 207, null from dual union all
 40  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:01:45','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 18, null from dual union all
 41  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:16:45','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 39, null from dual union all
 42  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:22:55','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 656, null from dual union all
 43  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:25:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1852, null from dual union all
 44  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:29:23','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 688, null from dual union all
 45  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:47:26','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 2258,10177846 from dual union all
 46  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 16:57:41','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 572, null from dual union all
 47  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 17:06:47','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1431, null from dual union all
 48  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 17:18:32','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 29, null from dual union all
 49  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 17:21:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 45, null from dual union all
 50  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 17:29:23','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 16, null from dual union all
 51  select 3018868, to_date('2013-01-16 17:36:47','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 490, null from dual
 52  /

Table created.
```

The query, using [tabibitosan](https://community.oracle.com/message/4473208):

```
SQL> with tabibitosan as
  2  ( select user_id
  3         , starttime
  4         , visit_duration_seconds
  5         , order_number
  6         , row_number() over (partition by user_id order by starttime)
  7           - row_number() over (partition by user_id, order_number order by starttime) grp
  8      from mytable
  9  )
 10  select user_id
 11       , starttime
 12       , visit_duration_seconds
 13       , order_number
 14       , case
 15         when order_number is null then
 16           sum(visit_duration_seconds) over (partition by user_id,grp order by starttime)
 17         end result
 18    from tabibitosan
 19   order by user_id
 20       , starttime
 21  /

   USER_ID STARTTIME           VISIT_DURATION_SECONDS ORDER_NUMBER     RESULT
---------- ------------------- ---------------------- ------------ ----------
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:03:50                     61                      61
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:08:18                    151                     212
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:15:43                     33                     245
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:16:37                     13                     258
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:18:01                   2011     10177888
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:24:35                   1172     10177884
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:32:03                   4731                    4731
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:33:27                    407                    5138
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:37:29                     74                    5212
   2875636 16-01-2013 18:48:55                     80                    5292
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:05:00                   1955                    7247
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:14:12                    326                    7573
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:23:39                    972                    8545
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:33:05                   5440                   13985
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:35:48                     43                   14028
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:41:10                     66                   14094
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:42:03                    100                   14194
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:42:12                   2414     10177940
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:49:05                    432     10177925
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:50:19                    183                    2194
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:52:46                   2061                    4255
   2875636 16-01-2013 19:52:53                    400                    4655
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:00:47                    338                    4993
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:08:58                    216                    5209
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:14:21                     58                    5267
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:14:26                    196                    5463
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:19:14                   2189                    7652
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:21:29                    424                    8076
   2875636 16-01-2013 20:24:42                    999                    9075
   2875636 16-01-2013 21:01:39                   1810                   10885
   2875636 16-01-2013 21:02:54                    525                   11410
   2875636 16-01-2013 21:10:06                     27                   11437
   2875636 16-01-2013 21:12:08                    282                   11719
   2875636 16-01-2013 21:51:02                      6                   11725
   2875636 16-01-2013 22:18:34                    173                   11898
   2875636 16-01-2013 23:02:58                    318                   12216
   2875636 16-01-2013 23:45:37                    207                   12423
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:01:45                     18                      18
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:16:45                     39                      57
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:22:55                    656                     713
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:25:54                   1852                    2565
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:29:23                    688                    3253
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:47:26                   2258     10177846
   3018868 16-01-2013 16:57:41                    572                     572
   3018868 16-01-2013 17:06:47                   1431                    2003
   3018868 16-01-2013 17:18:32                     29                    2032
   3018868 16-01-2013 17:21:57                     45                    2077
   3018868 16-01-2013 17:29:23                     16                    2093
   3018868 16-01-2013 17:36:47                    490                    2583

49 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: :Wow ,+1 for your approach and `tabibitosan` rocks !!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT user_id
       ,starttime
       ,visit_duration_seconds
       ,order_number
       ,CASE WHEN order_number is NULL THEN SUM (visit_duration_seconds) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY starttime ASC 
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
        ELSE NULL END result
  FROM tab;
```

I have ordered the rows based on the starttime in ascending order

This is the approach ,you can put some filters based on your requirement !

Comment: The result for the row with 4731 visit_duration_seconds needs to be 4731. Yours gives 8172. The rolling sums needs to reset when a non-empty order number has appeared.

Comment: @RobvanWijk:Thanks lemme try a different approach of whats you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.user_id, A.starttime, A.visit_duration_seconds, A.order_number,
    case when a.order_number is NULL then sum(b.visit_duration_seconds) else null end
from tablename A, tablename B
where B.user_id=A.user_id
and B.starttime <= A.starttime
group by A.user_id, A.starttime, A.visit_duration_seconds, A.order_number
order by A.user_id, A.starttime
```

See [Sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c0e/2)

Comment: The result for the row with 4731 visit_duration_seconds needs to be 4731. Yours gives 8172. The rolling sums needs to reset when a non-empty order number has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytics:

```
select user_id, visit_duration_seconds, order_number, 
       case when order_number is not null then null
       else sum(case when order_number is null then visit_duration_seconds end) 
               over (partition by user_id order by starttime) 
       end rolling_total
  from data;

   USER_ID VISIT_DURATION_SECONDS ORDER_NUMBER ROLLING_TOTAL
---------- ---------------------- ------------ -------------
   2875636                     61                         61 
   2875636                    151                        212 
   2875636                     33                        245 
   2875636                     13                        258 
   2875636                   2011 10177888                   
   2875636                   1172 10177884                   
   2875636                   4731                       4989 
   [...]
```